# converting data into time series data

Tags: r, time-series, data-manipulation

I tried to enter these commands but it does not work... can someone help please?

```
OPts <- read.csv(OILBRENT)
```

> Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
>     'file' must be a character string or connection

```
OPts <- ts(OILBRENT, start = c(jun-87), end = c(Jan-20), frequency =12)
```

> Error in ts(OILBRENT, start = c(jun - 87), end = c(Jan - 20), frequency = 12) : 
>     object 'jun' not found

```
OPts <- ts(OILBRENT, start = c(jun-87, 1), end = c(Dec-19, 12), frequency =12)
```

> Error in ts(OILBRENT, start = c(jun - 87, 1), end = c(Dec - 19, 12), frequency = 12) : 
>     object 'jun' not found

Comment: Please take a look at [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), to modify your question, with a smaller sample taken from your data (check `?dput()`). Posting images of your data or no data makes it difficult to impossible for us to help you!

Comment: What is `U`? do not use slang here.

Comment: @fcm U is the letter next to I. Given the sentence it's likely a typo...

Comment: First, U need to import the data successfully. Once that task has been accomplished, you need to find Jun.

Answer (score 0):

seems you are missing some quotation marks.

`read.csv` expects either a `character` pointing to a file, or a connection. If you are trying to read a file in your current working directory try `OPts <- read.csv("OILBRENT")`.

Both `ts` commands seem to be failing because the `start` parameter is expecting either a number or a numeric vector. When you write `start = c(jun-87)`, R will try to find an object `jun` and then compute the difference `jun - 87`. From the man page for `ts`:

```
  start: the time of the first observation.  Either a single number or
          a vector of two integers, which specify a natural time unit
          and a (1-based) number of samples into the time unit.  See
          the examples for the use of the second form.
```